# How do I make a JSON object produce HTML on the page

Tags: json, image, object, for-loop, each

Here is my JSON

```
var gal = [
    {
    "folder":"nu_images",
    "pic":"gd_42.jpg",
    "boxclass":"pirobox_gall",
    "alt":"Rand Poster 1",
    "title":"Rand Poster 1",
    "thfolder":"th",
    "thumbpic":"th_gd_42.jpg"
    },
    {
    "folder":"nu_images",
    "pic":"gd_13.jpg",
    "boxclass":"pirobox_gall",
    "alt":"Explosive Pixel Design",
    "title":"Explosive Pixel Design",
    "thfolder":"th",
    "thumbpic":"th_gd_13.jpg"
    }
];
```

and here is my for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < gal.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML = "<a href=\"" + "http:\/\/galnova.com\/" + gal[i].folder + "\/" + gal[i].pic + "\"" + "rel=\"gallery\"" + "class=\"" + gal[i].boxclass + "\"" + "title=\"" + gal[i].title + "\">" + "<img src=\"" + "http:\/\/galnova.com\/" + gal[i].folder + "\/" + "th\/" + gal[i].thumbpic + "\"" + "border=\"0\"" + "alt=\"" + gal[i].alt + "\"" + "title=\"" + gal[i].title + "\"\/>" + "</a>"
};
```

I am trying to make my JSON show all of the objects in HTML one after the other. I can get it to show the first one or whatever number I put into the array but I don't know how to make it generate a list of them.

Here is a link to my jsfiddle. Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/o7cuxyhb/10/

It's being generated here `<p id="gallery"></p>` just not correctly.

Comment: That is not JSON. It is simply a javascript array literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting your html with every loop iteration:

```
document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML = ...
                                             ^---
```

Perhaps you want something more like

```
document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML += ...
                                             ^---
```

which will concatenation the original html contents with your new stuff.

And technically, you shouldn't be doing this in a loop. Changing `.innerHTML` like that causes the document to be reflowed/re-rendered each time you change `.innerHTML`, which gets very expensive when you do it in a loop. You should be building your html as a plain string, THEN adding it to the dom.

e.g.

```
   var str = '';
   foreach(...) {
       str += 'new html here';
   }
   document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML += str;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This works much more efficient I hope!!! http://jsfiddle.net/o7cuxyhb/17/ Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < gal.length; i++) {
document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML += "<a href=\"" + "http:\/\/galnova.com\/" + gal[i].folder + "\/" + gal[i].pic + "\"" + "rel=\"gallery\"" + "class=\"" + gal[i].boxclass + "\"" + "title=\"" + gal[i].title + "\">" + "<img src=\"" + "http:\/\/galnova.com\/" + gal[i].folder + "\/" + "th\/" + gal[i].thumbpic + "\"" + "border=\"0\"" + "alt=\"" + gal[i].alt + "\"" + "title=\"" + gal[i].title + "\"\/>" + "</a>" };
```

Add a += instead of an = after innerHTML

Comment: Oh my goodness guys!!! I love both of you so much. I was torturing myself over this and was frantically checking the syntax for this over and over again. += who knew!!!?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function displayJson(jsonArray){
  var container = document.getElementById("gallery");
  for (var i=0; i<jsonArray.length; i++){
     var newElement = document.createElement("a").innerHTML = jsonToHtml(jsonArray[i])
     container.appendChild(newElement);
  }
}

function jsonToHtml(jsonObj){
 //Define your dom object here
 var el = document.createElement("a").innerHTML = '' // you code here
 ...
 return el;  
}

displayJson(gal);
```